# UIScrollView scrollViewWillEndDragging: targetContentOffset: not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Why is this not working? I have a breakpoint set at `targetContentOffset->y = -50.0f;` and it is being hit, not sure why it's  not having any effect.

Yes paging = NO.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -50.0f) {
        targetContentOffset->y = -50.0f;
    }
    else {
        *targetContentOffset = CGPointZero;

        // Need to call this subsequently to remove flickering.
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the condition being entered? Is the delegate method being called properly?

Comment: @0x7fffffff Yes it is, I have a breakpoint set on the third line down and it is being reached. It's just doing `targetContentOffset->y = -50.0f;` has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be your answer.

[scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset: not working on the edges of a UISCrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880434/scrollviewwillenddraggingwithvelocitytargetcontentoffset-not-working-on-the-e)

Theres a `UIScrollView` bug with setting the `targetContentOffset` of `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` while the scroll view is at it's default content offset.