# Center Cell UITableView When Scrolling Is Finished

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsindexpath

I have a UITableView, and I don't want it to stop between two cells when it stops after scrolling. So I need to move the cell which is the nearest of the Y center of the screen, when the velocity of the UITableView is less than a given value.

I'm sure I'm not the first who wants this effect, but I didn't find anything in my research. There must be a word for this that I don't know. Does someone have a link or something ?

I tried to do this on my own, but I don't find how to get the cell. I used `tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()`, so I have an array of indexPaths, but now I don't know how to call the corresponding cell. There is `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but this method creates a new cell, doesn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `-scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` in your table view delegate, just as in [this other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880434/scrollviewwillenddraggingwithvelocitytargetcontentoffset-not-working-on-the-e).

Basically, this method allows you to tweak the position where the velocity scroll will halt.

I can't help you more with code without knowing the structure of your table view (cells of variable height?).

Comment: I want the table view to decelerate after the end of the dragging, then move to the nearest cell when the velocity is less than a given value, is it possible with that function ? This function doesn't manage only what happen before the end of the dragging ?

Comment: This method allows to tweak the position where the scrolling will halt. It provides a much more natural scrolling, because the table view already knows where to stop before starting to scroll. There's no need to adjust the velocity, which would cause a visual speed increase or decrease.

Comment: My table view has cells of same height. But I want the cells to be bigger when they are "centered". In summary, I want a table view like in the "Storehouse" app for iPad.

Comment: Yep, you need a carousel, I understood that. If you want a "grow" effect for the center cell, I'd suggest you take a look at implementing a `UICollectionView` with a custom layout, that's precisely what it's meant to be used for.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to use UICollectionView, I don't really understand customs layouts, but it seems to be the right way. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you explain me quickly how should I implement the methods to have the carousel effect ? In which method should I change the size of the item ? Should I change the custom layout object or just directly the size of the item ? Thx

Comment: That's another question you should ask, after you've marked this one as answered or deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your ViewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.bounces = false
```